# View LinkedIn business page without login

Tags: linkedin

I've created a LinkedIn business page as an administrator, but no one can see it without being logged in (login page redirect). I know that there are LinkedIn company pages that can be accessed without a LinkedIn account.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you link a business page that you cannot see without being logged in?

Comment: @Narzard https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/11165908/

Comment: I have the same problem.. My company page cannot be accessed: https://de.linkedin.com/company/brodbeck-solutions Even without "beta" in the URL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only seems to happen with the new 'company-beta'

For example, this redirects to log in:

https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/7050191/

This does not:

https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-exchange

You can use either, so just use the old way.

**UPDATE**

I've done the donkey work for you:
https://www.linkedin.com/company/rubicon-audit-consulting

If the user is logged in, it will redirect to the new beta page. If not, it will continue to the old page. Open an incognito window and try it.

**For anyone else wondering how to do this...**

Open an incognito window and paste the URL, then remove '-beta'.

For example, your URL is:
https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/123456789/

Enter this in an incognito window: https://www.linkedin.com/company/123456789/

It will redirect you to the URL with the company name in (as long as it exists, of course).

Comment: @Jovica https://www.linkedin.com/company/rubicon-audit-consulting

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate this. I couldn't find solution online except to contact LinkedIn with page name request.

Comment: For future reference, just go into an incognito window and paste the url, then remove '-beta'.

Comment: Seems to not work anymore. Pasting any company URL in an Incognito window (or just another browser) and going to a company page still ends up on the LinkedIn "Login/Sign in" page". Really annoying.